# Looking for a post-apocalyptic movie about a man who is alone after an 'event'

Tags: story-identification, movie

I vaguely recall this film from when I was young. It has stuck in my mind and is probably at least partly responsible for my interest in post-apocalyptic films and literature.

The plot centred around an 'event' a flash of light or sound or something that had seemingly wiped out (vanished) all the humans on Earth. The narrative follows a lone man until he eventually finds some other survivors and they journey for a while. They then find a way to trigger the event, or the event happens again, and the film ends with the man truly alone.

I don't know any more details, but would love to find it again. Thanks!

Comment: Same answer. Different question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably remembering the visually stunning but awful [The Quiet Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089869/).  From Wikipedia:

> 5 July begins as a normal winter morning near Hamilton, New Zealand. At 6:12 a.m., the Sun darkens for a moment, and a red light surrounded by darkness is briefly seen.
>
> Zac Hobson (Bruno Lawrence) is a scientist working for Delenco, part of an international consortium working on "Project Flashlight", an experiment to create a global energy grid. He awakens abruptly; when he turns on his radio, he is unable to receive any transmissions. Zac gets dressed and drives into the deserted city. Investigating a fire, he discovers the wreckage of a passenger jet, but there are no bodies, only empty seats.

... and so on.

Comment: It was such a wierd movie. So was the book.

Comment: Lots of symbolism. For example, 6:12 am is 6 hours + 6 minutes + 6 minutes.